# Do I have to destroy the interstitial ad everytime I request a new Ads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I've seen in one of the tutorial that he destroys interstitial ad before requesting a new one is this right? Below is the sample code:

```
 private void RequestInterstitialAd()
{
    string interstitial_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"; // testid
    if (interstitialAd != null)
    {
        interstitialAd.Destroy();
    }
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitial_ID);
    interstitialAd.LoadAd(CreateNewRequest());
}

 public void ShowInsterstitialAd()
{
    if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded())
    {
        interstitialAd.Show();
    }
}

 private AdRequest CreateNewRequest()
{
    return new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();
}
```

Comment: From Google Documentation : 'interstitialAd.Destroy()' "This notifies the plugin that the object is no longer used and the memory it occupies can be reclaimed. Failure to call this method results in memory leaks".

Comment: If by `is this right?` you refer to `is he doing it` then yes. Do you *need to* do it? -  I feel like this can be tested quite easily by commenting the three according lines out and see what happens ;) Since none of the official examples mention this I guess someone just made it up for who knows which reason? ^^